# Why are the tests red on my Xcode project?

Tags: xcode, testing

When I look through my navigator on the left hand side my test framework for my project is red. How do I get it to turn black?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Anything red inside project navigator (The very first tab of left hand side pane) means: the corresponding file is missing. So if it is a target file, simply rebuild that target and Xcode makes a new one. But if it's a source code or any other resource file:

1. Select the file that marked with red color
2. Select browse button from the file inspector menu on the right hand side
3. Relocate the missing file

[image: File Inspector]

Some xctest targets will remain always red, because Xcode doesn't store a file for them. But it's not a problem.

Comment: Thanks for the help