# What does it mean when .xcodeproj files are shown in red in Xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode

What does it mean when Library files are shown in red, as in the screenshot below? Does it mean these files have been added, but there's something missing from them?

[image]

Comment: Not "similarly". The two things are completely unrelated. You don't get to change your question to include a completely different question.

Comment: Different questions but same answers. Checkout this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52796278/5623035

Answer (score 4):

This means that the reference to those two files has been lost. Someone moved or deleted them behind Xcode's back, and it no longer knows where they are.

Comment: What does the reference to the files mean?

Comment: Sometimes this is merely temporary and just quitting Xcode and opening the project again will fix the problem. But in some cases it's real, and you will need to import those files again if you want your workspace to behave correctly.

Comment: "The reference to files" is the imaginary arrow from the name in the project navigator to the actual file on disk. These things all signify actual files and Xcode can't find them.

Answer (score 2):

As matt said earlier, this is because the project (notably the `project.pbxproj` file) has a reference to these files/subprojects, but they’re not found in the location in question. This can happen if you deleted them, renamed them, or you cloned some repo where someone forgot to add these to source control even though they’re supposed to be. It’s hard to say what happened without more information, but Xcode merely is telling you that files are not where the main `project.pbxproj` file is expecting them to be.

Answer (score 0):

this happens when location mismatches or actual file is not there . search for these files in your mac , if is there , click on info and find the location . And if it differs , drag the file to app's necessary folder and in the **pop up select copy**